# Java servlet redirect with status 401 issue

Tags: java, servlets, status, response.redirect

I am having issue with Redirect in Java servlet. I want to use Status 401 ( Not authenticated ) instead of 302.

Let say that I have a protected resource with Url is "/protected". This Url mapped to ProtectedServlet. In doGet of ProtectedServlet, I will check whether the request is authenticated OR not, If not, the servlet will redirect the request to Login page. Here is my code:

**ProtectedServlet.java**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {

    boolean isAuth = this.checkAuth();

    if (isAuth == false) {

        // WAY1
        resp.setStatus(401);
        resp.sendRedirect(resp.encodeRedirectURL(loginUrl));

        // WAY2
        resp.setStatus(401);
        resp.setHeader("Location", resp.encodeRedirectURL(loginUrl));
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

1. If I used "WAY1", when I request "/protected", I will see LOGIN page
   but return Status is 302, NOT 401 as I expected.
2. If WAY2 used:  When I request "/protected", I WILL NOT see Login
   page. I see EMPTY page return with NO status.

Anyone know what I am wrong? Thanks.

Comment: [sendRedirect sets the result code to 302](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) so that explains the result of way 1.  For way 2 it would require that the browsers follows redirects after receiving an error code, and I have no idea whether that should even work.  What about way 1 makes it unacceptable for you?

Comment: WAY1 works but do you think it is correct because we are accessing protected resources and we are not authenticated so we should receive 401 status. Is that correct?

Comment: @Loc what SotiriosDelimanolis proposes may be a viable solution, or a hop via some error page (the latter would also allow you to give extended instructions and contact info to the user, should your application require that kind of user assistance)

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP protocol is well defined. The client sends an HTTP request and the server sends them back an HTTP response.

The HTTP response can only have one status code. You can see your options [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). In other words, you can't do a redirect by sending a 401. You could put a `Location` header in your 401 response but you would have to tell your client what to do with it because it isn't standard.

Instead of redirecting, if your user is not authenticated return a 401 and render the same Login page HTML, ie. do a `RequestDispatcher#forward(..)` to the login jsp.